# Kotlin/Native cInterop or konanc which one makes problem?

Tags: linux, kotlin-native

gtk3.def

```
headers = gtk/gtk.h
headerFilter = gtk/* gobject/* gio/*
```

build.sh

```
IPREFIX_linux=-I/usr/include
LINKER_ARGS_linux="-L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/local/lib -lglib-2.0 -lgio-2.0  -lgobject-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lharfbuzz -lcairo -lgtk-3"

if [ x$TARGET == x ]; then
case "$OSTYPE" in
  darwin*)  TARGET=macbook ;;
  linux*)   TARGET=linux ;;
  *)        echo "unknown: $OSTYPE" && exit 1;;
esac
fi

var=IPREFIX_${TARGET}
IPREFIX="${!var}"
var=LINKER_ARGS_${TARGET}
LINKER_ARGS=${!var}
var=COMPILER_ARGS_${TARGET}
COMPILER_ARGS=${!var} # add -opt for an optimized build.

if [ ! -f $DIR/gtk3 ]; then
  echo "Generating GTK stubs (once), may take few mins depending on the hardware..."
   
cinterop -compiler-options $IPREFIX/atk-1.0 -compiler-options $IPREFIX/gio-unix-2.0 -compiler-options $IPREFIX/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -compiler-options \
  $IPREFIX/cairo -compiler-options -I/opt/local/lib/glib-2.0/include \
  -compiler-options -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -compiler-options $IPREFIX/gtk-3.0 \
  -compiler-options $IPREFIX/glib-2.0 -def $DIR/gtk3.def -compiler-options $IPREFIX/harfbuzz \
  -compiler-options $IPREFIX/pango-1.0  -target $TARGET -o $DIR/gtk3 || exit 1
**// the cinterop command makes gtk3.klib which is ok! but the problem is next command.**
*konanc -target $TARGET Application.kt -l $DIR/gtk3 -linker-option "$LINKER_ARGS" -e "sample.gtk.main" -o $DIR/Main.kexe || exit 1* 
**// I tried konanc instead of kotlin-native but the error same like below. 
// also change target linux instead of linux_x64**
**// Application.kt starts sentence package sample.gtk**
```

error

```
/home/bob-kim/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld.gold invocation reported errors
The /home/bob-kim/.konan/dependencies/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc-8.3.0-glibc-2.19-kernel-4.9-2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ld.gold command returned non-zero exit code: 1.
output:
/tmp/konan_temp12575366956155761859/result.o:out:function gtk3_g_signal_connect_data_wrapper194: error: undefined reference to 'g_signal_connect_data'
/tmp/konan_temp12575366956155761859/result.o:out:function gtk3_g_object_unref_wrapper279: error: undefined reference to 'g_object_unref'
/tmp/konan_temp12575366956155761859/result.o:out:function gtk3_g_application_run_wrapper593: error: undefined reference to 'g_application_run'
/tmp/konan_temp12575366956155761859/result.o:out:function gtk3_gtk_widget_destroy_wrapper3089: error: undefined reference to 'gtk_widget_destroy'
/tmp/konan_temp12575366956155761859/result.o:out:function gtk3_gtk_widget_show_all_wrapper3095: error: undefined reference to 'gtk_widget_show_all'
/tmp/konan_temp12575366956155761859/result.o:out:function gtk3_gtk_application_new_wrapper3338: error: undefined reference to 'gtk_application_new'
/tmp/konan_temp12575366956155761859/result.o:out:function gtk3_gtk_container_add_wrapper3367: error: undefined reference to 'gtk_container_add'
/tmp/konan_temp12575366956155761859/result.o:out:function gtk3_gtk_window_set_title_wrapper3415: error: undefined reference to 'gtk_window_set_title'
/tmp/konan_temp12575366956155761859/result.o:out:function gtk3_gtk_window_set_default_size_wrapper3510: error: undefined reference to 'gtk_window_set_default_size'
/tmp/konan_temp12575366956155761859/result.o:out:function gtk3_gtk_application_window_new_wrapper4563: error: undefined reference to 'gtk_application_window_new'
/tmp/konan_temp12575366956155761859/result.o:out:function gtk3_gtk_button_box_new_wrapper4612: error: undefined reference to 'gtk_button_box_new'
/tmp/konan_temp12575366956155761859/result.o:out:function gtk3_gtk_button_new_with_label_wrapper4669: error: undefined reference to 'gtk_button_new_with_label'
```

Comment: I would guess the problem can be caused by trying to push all linker options under a single flag. Also, your cinterop invocation does not contain any linker options. Have you tried to look how similar projects do this? AFAIK, [this](https://github.com/Dominaezzz/kgl) one might be relevant. There also is a Kotlin/Native's official sample. It might be useful too: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/kotlin-native/samples/gtk.

Comment: Thank u. Now I can make kexe file!. But only practical purpose.